# Iterative SUMIF Function Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Consider the following table:

[image]

What I would like to be able to do is create something like on the right hand side.  This essentially requires telling Excel to sum all values for which the cell is zero until it encounters a 1, at which point it should begin the count again.  I imagine this can be done using VBA, so I just need to determine how to actually set up that code.  I imagine that the building blocks should be something like this:

```
Dim row As Long

Dim sum As List

row = Excel row definition

While ColB <> ""

  If ColB.value = 0 
  Append ColC.value to Sum
  Else Do Nothing

row = row + 1

Loop
```

Any help with the structure and syntax of the code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cel As Range, sRng As Range, oRng As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long: i = 1

    On Error GoTo halt
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Set Rng = .Range("B1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Rng.AutoFilter 1, 0
        Set sRng = Rng.Offset(1, -1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Rng.AutoFilter 1, 1
        Set oRng = Rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    If sRng.Areas.Count >= oRng.Areas.Count Then i = 2
    For Each cel In oRng.Areas
        If i > sRng.Areas.Count Then Exit For
        If cel.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Formula = _
                "=SUM(" & sRng.Areas(i).Address(True, True) & ")"
        Else
            cel.Cells(cel.Cells.Count).Offset(0, 1).Formula = _
                "=SUM(" & sRng.Areas(i).Address(True, True) & ")"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
Exit Sub
halt:
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

**Edit1:**
Above works regardless of how many zero's or one's you have in Column B.
If error occurs, it will exit. I leave the coding on how you want the error handled.

Comment: Thanks!  What do you mean by 'provided there's always a zero and two ones'?  That it will cause an error if the list only contains a single 'one'?  If so, why does that occur?

Comment: You got it right. The reason is I used Autofilter method. If nothing is filtered error occurred. So there should always be a zero. Why 2 ones? I used Areas property and output the sum based on the sequence of areas. If zero areas comes first, it will not put the formula to the correct position. So the 1st item should be one. Having only that one(first item) produces error on Areas as well, so there should be another one somewhere. I'll update my answer once I've figured another approach or somehow a workaround for the current codes short comings.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll need to read up a bit more on the Areas property.  I'll also be sure to accept your answer as soon as I get a chance to actually test things out.

Comment: When trying to run the code I receive the error "AutoFilter method of Range class failed'.  Would you happen to know why this comes up?

Comment: @114 I've edited it and fixed most of the problems I've enumerated above. Still the best approach I think.

Comment: I'm having some issues with the code.  Although I'm not receiving an error I don't actually get any output.  Any idea why it might believe it's executing without producing a result?

Comment: @114 That is correct, I put an error handler `On Error Goto halt`. Remove it to check the actual result. But it will only throw error if there are no zero's. I tried it in almost all scenarios and it works fine.